# Diamonds pattern between two functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs, pattern

I would like to have a diamonds pattern (or another pattern between) the two red functions. Additionally, it would be great to have the dotted line style of `$H_{S_2}(\beta)$` represented at the left of it (as it is usually done in the legend). The same legend style identification (that is the included pattern) should be represented at the left of `$W_{S_1}(\beta)$`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    xlabel near ticks,
    ylabel near ticks,
    myplot/.style={smooth,tension=0.5,mark=none,very thick}
}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 width=1.5\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight,
 axis x line=bottom,
 xmin=0,
 xmax=1,
 xtick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1},
 axis y line=left,
 ymin=70,
 ymax=120,
 ytick={75,85,95,105,115},
 ylabel={$w$},
 xlabel={$\beta$},
 %grid=major,
 legend style={
   at={(current bounding box.north-|current axis.east)},
   anchor=east,
   legend columns=2
}
]
%W_1 upper

\addplot+[color=red,dotted,myplot ]
 coordinates {
 (0, 100.3)
 (0.1,         98)
 (0.2,     95.5)
 (0.3,      92.7)
 (0.4,      89.7)
 (0.5,      86.4)
 (0.6,      82.7)
 (0.67,      80)    
}
 ;
\addplot[red,domain=0:0.67]{80};

\node at (0.2,90) {  \textcolor{red}{$W_{S_1}(\beta)$}};

\node at (0.2,100) { $H_{S_2}(\beta)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What precisely is a diamond pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `fillbetween` and `patterns` libs:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}    
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    xlabel near ticks,
    ylabel near ticks,
    myplot/.style={smooth,tension=0.5,mark=none,very thick}
}    

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 width=1.5\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight,
 axis x line=bottom,
 xmin=0,
 xmax=1,
 xtick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1},
 axis y line=left,
 ymin=70,
 ymax=120,
 ytick={75,85,95,105,115},
 ylabel={$w$},
 xlabel={$\beta$},
 %grid=major,
 legend style={
   at={(current bounding box.north-|current axis.east)},
   anchor=east,
   legend columns=2
}
]
%W_1 upper

\addplot+[color=red,dotted,myplot,name path=A]
 coordinates {
 (0, 100.3)
 (0.1,         98)
 (0.2,     95.5)
 (0.3,      92.7)
 (0.4,      89.7)
 (0.5,      86.4)
 (0.6,      82.7)
 (0.67,      80)    
}
 ;
\addplot[red,domain=0:0.67,name path=B]{80};

\addplot[pattern=crosshatch dots,pattern color=red] fill between[of=A and B];

\node at (0.2,90) {  \textcolor{red}{$W_{S_1}(\beta)$}};

\node at (0.2,100) { $H_{S_2}(\beta)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Hazel, that looks really good. Do you also have an idea how I can get the $W_{S_1}$ to stick out better? Perhaps having a white background to the box?

Comment: @Paul You could use the `contour` package to add a white halo around the text. (And please consider accepting the answer if it answers your original question.)

Comment: Thank you both very much.